# Using Bokeh HoverTool without Lable only value

Tags: python, hover, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh HoverTool for a simple circle plot.

I want to use HoverTool such that when I move the cursor on a circle I'll see the value, only the value without the label.

In my code now when I move the cursor I saw - "Lable:A" but I want to see - "A"

How to do that?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, CustomJSHover

# Sample data for circles
x_values = [1, ]
y_values = [6, ]
circle_labels = ['A']

# Create a ColumnDataSource from the data
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=x_values,
    y=y_values,
    label=circle_labels,
))

# Create the figure
p = figure(width=400, height=400, title="Circle Plot with Hover Tooltip")

# Add circles to the plot
circle_glyph = p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, color="navy", source=source)

# Define hover tool with custom tooltip
hover = HoverTool(renderers=[circle_glyph], tooltips=[("Label", "@label")],
                  formatters={"@label": "printf"})

# Add hover tool to the plot
p.add_tools(hover)

# Show the plot
# show(p)

# Show the plot
output_file("bokeh_plot.html", title='Bokeh Plot', mode='inline', root_dir=None)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your tooltips declaration, simply use:

```
tooltips=[("", "@label")]
```

Result:

[image]